# How would you declare a Texture object in the libgdx skin json file, using a region from a texture atlas?

Tags: java, libgdx, texture-atlas, skinning

I have a texture atlas that is linked to my `skin.json` file. The atlas contains a region named "game-title".
I would like to declare a `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture` object in the json file, to retrieve it later in my code via `skin.get(name, Texture.class)`.
I tried declaring it as follows, but it does not work - exception gets thrown - `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor): com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture`:

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture": {
  "game-title": {name: "game-title"}
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? What would be the correct way to do this?
Is trying to declare a `Texture` in such a way a correct thing to do, in the first place?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the atlas regions are automatically available through the skin as TextureRegions. I just tried it, and works without modifying the json file.

You can just call `skin.get(name, TextureRegion.class);` or `skin.getRegion(name);`

Unfortunately, the skin docs are not very clear about this. [libGdx docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin)